# Html Helpers and JSON/AJAX/Javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Html helpers in ASP.NET MVC are great but.. what happens when, as is often the case, I am passing the model object via json to the view and then wanting to do something with it? Seems like there is an void in the framework to deal with this common situation. I now have to do everything manually with javascript.

Comment: Where is the void? What are you trying to do?? Your question is not clear at all. MVC has built in JSON model binding, so if you pass a serialized JSON object to a MVC controller action, the default model binder (in MVC3 - it's built in) will bind to the object for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think its a void in the framework. After all you can use any JavaScript you like. I'd recommend checking out knockoutjs if you're doing lots of json manipulation.
Sorry, no link, I'm on my phone...